# Ajax don't show the value of countdown

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a probem with ajax , If I use the following code only with PHP I show the date correctly.

```
<h2><span class="clock" data-countdown="{{ $subasta->data_final}}"></span></h2>
```

However , when I try to use this with ajax I don't show the information about the dates , but the other information load correctly.

```
<h2><span class='clock' data-countdown='"+response[index].data_final+"'></span></h2>
```

Which is the problem?

All of the ajax code

```
success:  function (response) {
                    $(response).each(function(index,value)  {
                        $(".product-image-wrapper2").append("<div class='col-sm-4' style='height:500px;'><div class='nombre'>"+ response[index].nombre + "</div><h2><span class='clock' data-countdown='"+response[index].data_final+"'></span></h2><p>"+response[index].descripcion+"<p>"+ response[index].cant_actual +"<p><a class='pujar btn btn-warning'>Pujar</a>");                                                          
                        $(".product-image-wrapper2").append("</div>");
                    });


                },
```

Comment: This looks like a simple quote mismatch. Is the code you posted here the exact code you are running?

Comment: Yes , the code with ajax works correctly , the part of ajax I need to change is the first code.

Comment: just a guess, but if your countdown is created by binding to the class `.clock`, then your dynamically added countdowns are added after the DOM is loaded, so the binding does not occur. You might need to re-bind after successful ajax

Comment: I have the same problem , I try all of this :( , I will continue research :/